# How to position a pyqtgraph plot at a pixel position in the window?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have a project where I'm plotting 10 different graphs of data that's coming in over a serial port (I have an Arduino with a bunch of sensors and it's reporting the values, and I want to have a Python program to display graphs of all those values). I got it working with Tkinter and Matplotlib, but it's not able to run fast enough to keep up with the data stream (I'd like 30 frames per second). I've heard pyqtgraph is a good option, but all the examples I can find use a Grid structure to define the locations of the graphs within the window. I don't want a grid, I want to say "Place a 300x200 pixel graph at screen coordinates 1000,750". How can I do that? In my existing tkinter setup, I generate custom Graph objects which each have their own plt.figure() instances, and then I have these lines to place them:

```
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=tk_root)
plot_widget = self.canvas.get_tk_widget()
plot_widget.place(x,y,width,height)
```

How do I do the analogous operation in pyqtgraph? I'm looking at the examples and I see lines like `p1 = win.addPlot(title="Basic array plotting", y=np.random.normal(size=100))` and it seems like the function to add a plot to the window should have a location parameter, but it doesn't. Is there another function I need to call, along the lines of `p1.setPosition(x,y,w,h)`?

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you want to move the window or do you want to move an item within PlotWidget or similar? Also please provide a [mre], also maybe an image that illustrates what you want would help to understand you

Comment: As stated in the title, I hope to position the *plot* within the *window*. I intend for the window to be full-screened, and I'm asking how to position a plot at an arbitrary location within the window, as opposed to being bound to the built-in grid system.
I can't provide a reproducible example because if I could provide the example I'd be done.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand the OP wants to place some widget that shows a plot inside a window in a specific position with a predetermined size so for that you must use setGeometry() or move() + resize():

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget(self)
        self.plot_widget.setGeometry(1000, 750, 300, 200)
        # or
        # self.plot_widget.move(1000, 750)
        # self.plot_widget.resize(300, 200)

        self.plot_widget.plot(y=np.random.normal(size=100))
        self.plot_widget.setTitle("Basic array plotting")
        self.showMaximized()
        # or
        # self.showFullScreen()


def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is quite helpful. setGeometry was the critical function I was struggling to find in the docs.